# datetimepicker in Sonata Admin not working

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

How would I create a datetime field in the Sonata Admin Bundle which uses the sonata_type_datetime_picker? When I clicked submit, the Symfony Profiler will show error as show in the picture below.
[image: Error]

Here is my code:

EventAdmin.php

```
class EventAdmin extends Admin
    {
        // Fields to be shown on create/edit forms
        protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
        {
            $formMapper
                ->add('eventDate', 'sonata_type_datetime_picker', array(
                    'label' => 'Event Date',
                    'format' => 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
                    'dp_language' => 'en',
                    'dp_side_by_side'       => true,
                    'dp_use_current'        => false,
                    'datepicker_use_button' => false,
                ))  
            ;
        }
    }
```

Event.php

```
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $eventDate;

    /**
     * Set eventDate
     *
     * @param \DateTime $eventDate
     *
     * @return Event
     */
    public function setEventDate($eventDate)
    {
        $this->eventDate = $eventDate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get eventDate
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getEventDate()
    {
        return $this->eventDate;
    }
```

Comment: Did you try    ->add('eventDate', 'sonata_type_datetime_picker') without any options?

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc Ya, the datepicker is working without added any options because it use default options. `'format'=>DateTimeType::HTML5_FORMAT`. How can I specify my own display format?

Comment: i'm getting the same error - regardless of the format the error remains the same. symfony 3.2.1, sonata admin 3.1

Answer (score 2):

I believe your only options for formatting is a combination of these letters:

```
'format'=>"YYYY-MM-D h:mm:ss a" //2015-01-19 8:05:00 AM
```

You can add or subtract each letter for different formats.
For instance, `YYYY-MMM-DD HH:mm` will display as `2015-Jan-19 08:05`

Comment: If I add my own options instead of using the default options, it will showing the error. Adding `'format'` will change the form datetimepicker display format, but it will generate a error if the form is submitted.

Comment: Strange, I ran an example with exactly all your settings and it worked. It keeps the format and it saves it in the database. Did you update your schema? What does --dump-sql show you? Maybe your database expects a certain format?

Comment: The profiler didnt show any doctrine logs yet so I think it is happen before saving into database. It just show the flash message `An error has occurred during the creation of item "AppBundle\Entity\Event:000000007701e48b000000001dceecdf".` and with the datepicker field highlighted in red color. It is possible it is a html validation error?

Comment: I got no error message on save, but the date got screwed up when I changed the default format. I just wanted to remove the AM.PM and use 24h format, like this `'format' => 'MMM d, YYYY, H:mm:ss'`

Comment: Things might have changed since then.